# Configure Azure auto unseal in running Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have a running instance of Vault deployed with Kubernetes+Helm. It has a single unseal key.
Is there a way to configure it to auto unseal with Azure? All tutorials I have followed generate new keys and I can't figure out how to "import" current unseal key into Azure so it is used to auto unseal.